# c++ ordinary lookup vs argument dependent lookup

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

Considering this sample described in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl:

```
namespace A {
      struct X;
      struct Y;
      void f(int);
      void g(X);
}

namespace B {
    void f(int i) {
        f(i);   // calls B::f (endless recursion)
    }
    void g(A::X x) {
        g(x);   // Error: ambiguous between B::g (ordinary lookup)
                //        and A::g (argument-dependent lookup)
    }
    void h(A::Y y) {
        h(y);   // calls B::h (endless recursion): ADL examines the A namespace
                // but finds no A::h, so only B::h from ordinary lookup is used
    }
}
```

I am wondering why the ambiguity appears since the ADL rules are not taken into account if

> "the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following".

Here B::g can be found by unqualified lookup as explained in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup thanks to the rule

> For a name used in the definition of a function, either in its body or as part of default argument, where the function is a member of user-declared or global namespace, the block in which the name is used is searched before the use of the name, then the enclosing block is searched before the start of that block, etc, until reaching the block that is the function body. Then the namespace in which the function is declared is searched until the definition (not necessarily the declaration) of the function that uses the name, then the enclosing namespaces, etc.

Then my question is why are ADL rules considered in this case?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think it should not be taken into account?

Comment: First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:

Comment: 1) a declaration of a class member
2) a declaration of a function at block scope (that's not a using-declaration)
3) any declaration that is not a function or a function template (e.g. a function object or another variable whose name conflicts with the name of the function that's being looked up)

Comment: I can see none of these three in this code snippet.

Comment: then if the function found by unqualified lookup is found but not at block scope, ADL rules are considered?

Answer (score 6):

The full quote is

> First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:
>
> 1. a declaration of a class member
> 2. a declaration of a function at block scope (that's not a using-declaration)
> 3. any declaration that is not a function or a function template (e.g. a function object or another variable whose name conflicts with the name of the function that's being looked up)

What this means is that ADL is ignored only when unqualified lookup produces one of the above three results.  Since we are not dealing with a class member, the function is declared at namespace scope, not block scope, and we only find functions we continue on and use ADL.

Comment: Then what does a declaration of a function at block scope means (the declaration is inside the current scope?)

Comment: @FlashMcQueen It is a function that is declared at [block scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope#Block_scope)

Comment: @NathanOliver The *block scope* includes global scope? Even though i declared type-specific function and the type at global scope, the specific one is called instead of generic one.

Comment: @rosshjb block scope does not include the global scope. That has namespace scope.  Without seeing the code you are using, I can't say what is going on.  If you would like clarification, you should post a questions.

Answer (score 1):

> why are ADL (argument dependant lookup) rules considered in this case?

Because there may be better matches in the associated namespaces. E.g.:

```
void f(void*);

namespace A {
struct X;
void f(X*);
}

int main() {
    A::X* x = 0;
    f(x); // A::f is the best match.
}
```

This mechanism is often used for [`swap` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

> `std::swap` may be specialized in namespace `std` for user-defined types, but such specializations are not found by ADL (the namespace `std` is not the associated namespace for the user-defined type). **The expected way to make a user-defined type swappable is to provide a non-member function swap in the same namespace as the type**: see Swappable for details.
>
> Any lvalue or rvalue of this type can be swapped with any lvalue or rvalue of some other type, using unqualified function call `swap()` in the context where both `std::swap` and the user-defined `swap()`s are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question. I came here looking for the answer myself, and I think I have been able to come up with an example which falls under this rule

> the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:
>
> - ...
> - a declaration of a function at block scope (that's not a using-declaration)

and switches off ADL indeed.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace x {
    struct type {};
    void fn(type) { std::puts("ADL"); }
}

int main() {
    // Forward function declaration within the function scope.
    // This way "Regular" gets printed out.
    // Comment this declaration out and you'll get "ADL".
    void fn(x::type);

    fn(x::type{});
    return 0;
}
void fn(x::type) { std::puts("Regular"); }
```

If you put this forward declaration before the **main**, you'll get an *ambiguous call* as both the usual unqualified name lookup and ADL would kick in. But having declared the function within the function scope, everything works as promised.

Still not sure how often one can find this in a wild. At least, I have not seen anything like that yet and can hardly imagine where such a coding trick would be beneficial.